# Python Script to backup a directory

Tags: python, windows-xp, backup, rar

```
#Filename:backup_ver1

import os
import time

#1 Using list to specify the files and directory to be backed up
source = r'C:\Documents and Settings\rgolwalkar\Desktop\Desktop\Dr Py\Final_Py'

#2 define backup directory
destination = r'C:\Documents and Settings\rgolwalkar\Desktop\Desktop\PyDevResourse'

#3 Setting the backup name
targetBackup = destination + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.rar'

rar_command = "rar.exe a -ag '%s' %s" % (targetBackup, ''.join(source))
##i am sure i am doing something wrong here - rar command please let me know

if os.system(rar_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', targetBackup
else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'

O/P:- Backup FAILED
```

winrar is added to Path and CLASSPATH under Environment variables as well - anyone else with a suggestion for backing up the directory is most welcome

Comment: ok i did that(imported the tarfile module) and it ran quietly -- i did not give any message as there was nothing added to produce a message - i checked the location destination=os.path.join(root,"Documents and Settings","rgolwalkar","Desktop","Desktop","PyDevResourse") But there was no backup found. second if i add:- if os.system(tar) == 0: print 'Successful backup to', targetBackup else: print 'Backup FAILED' --it comes up with an error if os.system(tar) == 1: TypeError: system() argument 1 must be string, not TarFile

Comment: Just curious, why are you using rar instead of something cross-platform such as zip, which is built into python?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of writing your own backup script you could use python tool called rdiff-backup, which can create incremental backups?

Answer (score 0):

The `source` directory contains spaces, but you don't have quotes around it in the command line. This might be a reason for the backup to fail.

To avoid problems like this, use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system`:

```
subprocess.call(['rar.exe', 'a', '-ag', targetBackup, source])
```

Answer (score 0):

if the compression algorithm can be something else and its just to backup a directory, why not do it with python's own tar and gzip instead? eg

```
import os
import tarfile
import time
root="c:\\"
source=os.path.join(root,"Documents and Settings","rgolwalkar","Desktop","Desktop","Dr Py","Final_Py")
destination=os.path.join(root,"Documents and Settings","rgolwalkar","Desktop","Desktop","PyDevResourse")
targetBackup = destination + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + 'tar.gz'    
tar = tarfile.open(targetBackup, "w:gz")
tar.add(source)
tar.close()
```

that way, you are not dependent on `rar.exe` on the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot ghostdog74-- let me check the code and execute it that way --- i will check and paste the O/P

Comment: ghostdog74 --  I get the error :- 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\rgolwalkar\Desktop\Desktop\Dr Py\Final_Py\backup_ver1.py", line 16, in <module>
    tar = tarfile.open(targetBackup, "w:gz")
NameError: name 'tarfile' is not defined

Comment: tarfile is a module, import it like `import tarfile`

Comment: ok i did that and it ran quietly -- i did not give any message as there was nothing added to produce a message - i checked the location 
destination=os.path.join(root,"Documents and Settings","rgolwalkar","Desktop","Desktop","PyDevResourse")
But there was no backup found.
second if i add:- 
if os.system(tar) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', targetBackup
else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'

--it comes up with an error
if os.system(tar) == 1:
TypeError: system() argument 1 must be string, not TarFile

Comment: why do you use `os.system`? `tar` is a unix command. if you do `os.system(tar)`, you are actually calling the tar command. the `tar` in the Python script is just the instance of tarfile `module`, NOT the `tar` command. Put in some print statements and make sure your directories are correct path.  It works fine for me on my *nix.